# Laravel 5.3 Update data base record with button

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

Hello i am learning Laravel at collage got my project simple open ticket system which has users roles and tickets for broken inventory. When subbmited ticket it must be seen by worker and acssepted  by pressing button (Priimti) i done .blade form

```html
<div class="row">

  <h3>Viso gedimų: {{ $gedimai->total() }} </h3>
  <!-- Table -->
  <table class="table table-condensed">
    <thead>
      <th>Numeris</th>
      <th>Aprašymas</th>
      <th>Korpusas</th>
      <th>Meistras</th>
      <th>Priimta</th>
      <th>Atlikta</th>
      <th>Data</th>
      <th></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      @foreach($gedimai as $gedimas)
      <tr>
        <form action="{{ route('gedimas.priimti') }}" method="post">
          <td>{{ $gedimas->id }}</td>
          <td>{{ $gedimas->body }}</td>
          <td>{{ $gedimas->korpusas }} </td>
          <td>{{ $gedimas->meistras }}</td>


          <td>
            <td>{{ $gedimas->priimta }} <input type="hidden" name="priimta" value="{{ $gedimas->priimta }}"> </td>
            @if ($gedimas->priimta == '0')
            <span class="label label-warning">Naujas</span> {{ csrf_field() }}
            <td><button type="submit">Priimti</button></td>
        </form>
        @else
        <span class="label label-success"> Priimtas</span> @endif

        </td>


        <td> @if ($gedimas->priimta == '0' AND $gedimas->priimta == '0')

          <span class="label label-info"> - </span> @elseif ($gedimas->atlikta == '0')
          <span class="label label-warning">Taisoma</span>
          <input type="hidden" name="id" type="POST" value="gedimas.atlikta"> {{ csrf_field() }}
          <td><button type="submit">Atlikta</button></td>

          @else
          <span class="label label-success"> Gedimas pašalintas</span> @endif
        </td>

        <td>{{ $gedimas->created_at }}</td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach {{ $gedimai->links()}}
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
@endsection
```

added to GedimasController function to accsept (priimti)

```html
       public function priimti(Request $request)
    {

$id = Gedimas::where('id', $request['id'])->first();
         $id = $request->get('id');
          DB::table('gedimas')
            ->where('id', '=', $id)
            ->update(['priimta' => $request->status, 'priimta' => 1]);
        

return redirect()->back();
        
        }
```

and added route

```
Route::post('/pranesti', ['uses' => 'GedimasController@store']);
```

but unfotianatly it will not updating database row priimta which is boolean with default value "0" i just need to make it "1".

Thank you.

Comment: If you are just updating one row why do mass update syntax? See first example here, https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#updates

Comment: Hello like i said i am really new to laravel and trying to update only selected ticket and do not know anything about mass update

Comment: `$gedimas = Gedimas::find($request[id]);
$gedimas->priimta = 1;
$gedimas->save();`

Comment: Thank you for helping me no i am getting error  ErrorException in GedimasController.php line 89:
Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id'

Comment: and line 89 is $gedimas = Gedimas::find($request[id]);

Comment: $request['id']   typo.

Comment: ErrorException in GedimasController.php line 90:
Creating default object from empty value and lin 90 is         $gedimas->priimta = 1;

Comment: i think i done everything wrong here

Comment: If you are using tinyint mysql type for your boolean, the 1 should work.

Comment: priimta tinyint(1)   No 0

Comment: yes it is tiny int in database

Comment: What happens when you do dd($gedimas); right after the find()? Is it printing the model info out?

Comment: and here i am getting null

Comment: Make sure there actually is a  Gedimas of that id in your database.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/0CWyn there is a screenshot and i pressing first button Priimti all those table generated from database which i added using other form sorry for now its only on local mashine so cant lett you see it yourself

Comment: and Numeris is ID of tickets and where are 0 thre is values from priimti row and they all are from database

Comment: and http://imgur.com/a/uJqZb database structure and http://imgur.com/a/rnytk records in it

Comment: i done it changed form <input type="hidden" name="priimta" value="{{ $gedimas->priimta }}"> to <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $gedimas->id }}"> and it works THANK YOU SO MUCH for your time and help!!!!